# Provider updating all reusable widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a reusable widget which is children in a column(3 in number for demonstration purpose).
Each reusable widget has a textField and a Text to display what has been entered in the textField.
When one of the textfields in the reusable widgets is used to enter a number, that number is updated in all the Reusable widget.How do I resolve this issue?
And what if Reusable widget was used in a ListView.builder, how would I be able to update only a particular textfield?

Here is my Provider class:

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _number = 0.0;
  double get number {
    return _number;
  }

  void enterNumber(TextEditingController textController) {
    _number = double.parse(textController.text);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

my Main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => AppState())
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

TextEditingController tile_1_Controller = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController tile_2_Controller = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController tile_3_Controller = TextEditingController();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        ReusableTile('Tile 1', tile_1_Controller),
        ReusableTile('Tile 2', tile_2_Controller),
        ReusableTile('Tile 3', tile_3_Controller)
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Reusable widget:

```
class ReusableTile extends StatelessWidget {
  String tileTitle;
  TextEditingController textController;
  ReusableTile(this.tileTitle, this.textController, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        title: Text(
          tileTitle,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        subtitle: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: MyTextField('Number', 'Enter number', textController)),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () => provider.enterNumber(textController),//method to update the field value
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.done,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: Consumer<AppState>(
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return Text(
              '${state.number}',//this displays the number entered in textField
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `enterNumber` method to update the number it updates the number, but you are displaying the same number on each widget. Doesn't matter which widget calls the method and update. It's still going to be updated for all widgets.

make these changes:

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<double> _number = [0.0,0.0,0.0];
  List<double> get number {
    return _number;
  }

  void enterNumber(TextEditingController textController,int Index) {
    _number[index] = double.parse(textController.text);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Reusable Widget (add one more variable Index):

```
class ReusableTile extends StatelessWidget {
  String tileTitle;
  int indexNum;
  TextEditingController textController;
  ReusableTile(this.tileTitle, this.textController,this.indexNum {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        title: Text(
          tileTitle,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        subtitle: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: MyTextField('Number', 'Enter number', textController)),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () => provider.enterNumber(textController,indexNum),//method to update the field value
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.done,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: Consumer<AppState>(
          builder: (context, state, child) {
            return Text(
              '${state.number[indexNum]}',//this displays the number entered in textField
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when using pass the Custom Widget pass the indexNum;

```
ReusableTile('Tile 1',0 , tile_1_Controller),
ReusableTile('Tile 2',1 , tile_2_Controller),
ReusableTile('Tile 3',2 , tile_3_Controller)
```